# What is the proper way to insert millions of records from a csv file into a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, csv, sqlbulkcopy

I have to insert 40 million records from a `.csv` file into a database and below is the process I followed.

- Windows Service 1:

  - Reading the CSV
  - validating the records
  - inserting valid records into success table (intermediate table) using `SqlBulkCopy`.
- Windows Service 2.

  - Getting 10 000 records from success table at a time
  - running a foreach for these 10 000
  - sending each record to database to insert into the main table.

Windows Service 1 takes about 30-40 Min but windows service 2 takes about 5 Hours to complete the task (minimum time). I have 2 ways to do this but cannot decide which is better and open for suggestions.

1. Creating 4 separate windows service and processing 40000 records simultaneously
2. Using a job watch we can use while loop
3. Calling procedure async from windows service

My biggest doubt here is that we are using transactions in procedure and will async work with it because as per my assumption using transaction locks the table and other process needs to work on it.

Comment: Millions? SqlBulkCopy is the only one. `running a foreach` is probably the weak area. If you are using cursors consider rewriting the query so it is set based.

Comment: We are using sqlbulkcopy to in windows service 1 but we perform certain validation in second windows service procedure so hence cannot use bulkcopy.Another thing her is that when we use bulk copy lets assume a set of 1 lakh records to be inserted at a time using sql bulk copy then even if one record fails i need to log this or atleast need to know which record has this error hence that is not possible using bulkcopy

Comment: Bit if a different approach, but this would be nothing for SSIS to do? The integration services have a bulk insert where you can transform in the middle. I doubt VERY much that it would take over an hour in SSIS

Comment: Why is service 2 doing separate insert statements, why isn't it just `insert into ... select`?

Answer (score 2):

I think your using the wrong tool for this job.
c# apps might do the trick but there is a much more powerful way to do this using integration services.

I am guessing here, but these tables in the middle are to transform or check, or maybe to batch the import down?

SSIS can do all of these things using it log limit and SQL Bulk Import tools. I currently do hospital data imports which is around 8,000,000 records each night and it takes me a matter of minutes not hours to do.

A good read too around how SQL deals with such large data inputs is [this article](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/adventures-big-data-how-import-16-billion-rows-single-table)

Comment: Currently I'm looking at ssis and never used it before so any such articles would help me a lot(looking at youtube and google search results currently).The intermediate table is used because we have values in the csv file that are linked to another table and we need to insert that primary key into the main table(like we have a name from csv and we insert the name into this intermediate table and then update the primary key for that user into this table and insert only the primary key in the second table)

Comment: Ahh yeah, I have that issue in my dataset too. Current I run a SQL command that alters my destination table removed the PK and set it at the end of the batch. I know its a bit risky but I have a clustered index on that table and to create another would chew into compute time. If you have pluralsight it has some great SSIS stuff on there

Comment: Currently we do not have SSIS and pluralsight installed on our system do we have any other ways to do this because creating sql command is ok but since its a bank project cannot take that risk as verifying these accounts is again a difficult task for me.Totally lost now and thinking of writing 10 windows services any suggestions

Comment: I would suggest avoiding writing services. A good way to think of it, if your already at the data layer, don't try and jump out just to go back in. I would strongly advise installing integration services. Is there a reason you can't do that? It is free and packages with MSSQL if you have SQL standard. If you absolutely can't use SSIS, you could use SQL bulk insert tech with SQL agent (This is not a nice solution, lots might go wrong here)